# How to assign individual dictionary values to individual variables in python(not interested in loops)?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, command, python-idle

In my program, I can't seem to be able to pass individual string values from dictionary key/value pairs to ordinary string variables. In my program I gather the various command line options into a dictionary:

meta = {'author':'John Smith', 'title':'The Outcast', 'book id':'123456' }

The above works and will print out fine when I use *print(meta)*.I set each of the above entries like this:

author = 'John Smith'

meta['author'] = author

No problems. Note that I am successfully filling up the dictionary.

Then when I either try and assign a dict value from this dictionary to a variable in the recommended way, it always fails. Examples:

print(meta['author'])

*None.*

and...

auth = meta['author']

print(auth)

*None*

And the dictionary get() method also fails in the same way -- also gives None. I've also tried str() to perhaps convert the value objects but that doesn't work either.

Now the strange and baffling part. When I do this in the python IDLE environment:

```
    >>> a = {'author':'John Smith', 'title':'The Outcast', 'book     id':'123456' }
    >>>print(a)
    >>>{'author':'John Smith', 'title':'The Outcast', 'book id':'123456' }
    >>>b = a
    >>>print b
    >>>{'author':'John Smith', 'title':'The Outcast', 'book id':'123456' }
```

....it works !!

Why don't python dictionaries in the command line real programming environment behave like dictionaries in the IDLE environment?

So two questions. First, in my program, how can I just assign a simple dictionary string value to a string variable from a series of stored key/value dictionary items. I'm not interested in loops or generators. I need a simple dictionary method or way that does something like this:

author = meta['author'] (but this way does not appear to work)

Second question. Why is there such a gross mismatch in dictionary operation and capability between the python IDLE environment and the command line or real programming environment(python.exe)? I was really shocked at this apparent difference because many pythoneers learning python and using this simple IDLE IDE will be misled concerning dictionary behaviours in real programs. Dictionary behaviour and capability in the command line environment seems to act quite different from that of IDLE. Why? This was a very frustrating and disappointing discovery.

I'm using python 3.4 on Windows 10.

Comment: I don't seem to have any problem. I tried it with python 3.4 in windows 10 (virtual machine). Would you post your code ?

Comment: Thanks sunhs, but I made a goof ad found it fairly quickly. Forgot to mention that I was using two different returned dictionary lists and I eventually discovered that I was trying to access items from the wrong dictionary set. Found it and its all working perfectly now. My humble apologies for wasting anyone's time. That's what comes of trying to work too fast...

Comment: I believe you can delete a question submitted in error.  If not, please edit to add disclaimer at top and remove incorrect statements.